# Templating System and Plugin System

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, joomla

How to create template/theme system and plugin system for a custom CMS similar to Wordpress or joomla?

**Edit:**

I don't want to use any templating engine similar to wordpress; a reason why it is famous for templating.

Comment: Do you really want to build a new one? I guess you could use a standalone template system that already exists, like this one : http://www.twig-project.org/

Answer (score 1):

if you're looking to build a custom CMS why don't you pick a php framework and build on top of it. Why build from scratch when you an start with a proven and tested framework. Codeigniter is dead simple and Yii has already built a plugin system into its framework via components and modules: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/basics.module

Unless you're just trying to learn for yourself, there's really no benefit to building from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

```
$varArray = array('firstVar' => 'the value', 'secondVar' => 255);
$varArray['theThirdVar'] = 12345;
foreach($varArray as $name => $value){
    $$name = $value;
}
include ('templates/template.php');
```

in the `template.php` then do something like:

```
<?echo $firstVar;?>
```

this then should give you `the Value`

EDIT:
This is a minimal example.
You also could take a look into codeigniter source.
They also use this kindo of Template System.

Comment: This. Best practice. But I'd use just extract() instead of the foreach. Also personally I've transitioned to a `include(template("block"));` which adds a minor flexibility level atop.

Comment: jep extract would be possible, too. also it would add more security options which else must be implemented by yourself.